# Confusion with servlet session

Tags: java, session, servlets

Seems like a simple query, but wanted to be clear.

Suppose I have added a object in to user session.

```
AClass aObj = new AClass();
aObj.setValue("a");
request.getSession().setAttribute("aSessionName", aObj);
```

Now, If I make and changes in a object in the line below where i have saved it in session like:

```
aObj.setValue("b");
```

After this, if I try to retrieve AClass object from session like:

```
AClass bObj = (AClass)request.getSession().getAttribute("aSessionName");
```

Will the session return me **AClass** object which has value as **"a"** or **"b"**?

Comment: What stops you from going ahead to try that out?

Comment: @Unihedron: I wanted to know the reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an object to the session, the reference of the object will be stored. It will not be cloned, so the same object will be kept in the session that you have.

So if they are the same and you call `setValue("b")` on your object after you have put it into the session, since they are the same, you are modifying the same object. So when you get it next time from the session, it will have the value `"b"`.

**Note:**

One thing to note here. Sessions may be persisted to disk between server restarts; or if you have multiple servers clustered, the session (along with its attributes) may be transferred between servers. In such cases the attribute values stored in the session might not be the same reference.

Suggestion: whenever you want to modify an object that is stored in the session, you should always acquire it from the session first, modify it then set it back again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If your application contains very many sessions, then it might serialize some of them to free memory. So if your session was serialized and deserialized then you have another instance of AClass with value of 'a'.